# Count of chars in char array in descending order

Tags: java, hashmap

There is a `char array` as shown below. Need to print the count of each character in the descending order of the count.

```
char arr[] = {'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B','E','E'};
```

Looking for an efficient solution to this problem.
I have tried with `HashMap`, `ArrayList` combinations.
Is there a way to to do this with `HashMap` alone, without using `ArrayList`(or any other List implementations).

Comment: I tried with HashMap and ArraList.

Comment: Is there a way to do the sorting without using ArrayList for sorting purpose?

Comment: By descending order you mean by letters or by counting?

Comment: descending order of count

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try again using `TreeMap` but override the compare. Do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] arr = {'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B','E','E'};
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (char c: arr){
        if (!map.containsKey(c)){
            map.put(c, 1);
        }else{
            map.put(c, map.get(c)+1);
        }
    }
    ValueComparator vc = new ValueComparator(map);
    Map<Character, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>(vc);
    sortedMap.putAll(map);
    System.out.println(sortedMap);
}

public class ValueComparator implements Comparator<Character>   {

    Map<Character, Integer> map;

    public ValueComparator(Map<Character, Integer> map){
        this.map = map;
    }


    @Override
    public int compare(Character a, Character b) {
        if (map.get(a) >= map.get(b)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        } // returning 0 would merge keys 
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{A=5, E=5, B=3, C=2, D=1}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @gonzo. Is there a way to do away with TreeMap?

Comment: You want the final collection to be a `Map` or you mean not using `TreeMap` in the solution at all?  If you want the final collection to be a `Map` just change the line to `Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(vc);`

Comment: I want the final solution in a map, but not TreeMap.

Comment: @user3677652 I've updated answer to have the final sorted collection to be a type of `Map`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @user3677652 a `TreeMap` **is** a `Map`

Comment: @C.Champagne, I am trying to do this with HashMap alone (without TreeMap)

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is not the correct solution to this.  I would suggest using `TreeMap` instead.  Really any `SortedMap` will do.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

I believe this solution is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I need to print the count of each char in the descending order of the count. TreeMap sorts the values based on keys. It will be in alphabetical order. I want the result based on the count.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete Code, I am using `TreeMap` where `Char` is the Key and the count of that Char is value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        char arr[] = { 'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'B',
                'A', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'E' };
        Map<Character, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>(Collections.reverseOrder());

        for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
            if (myMap.containsKey(arr[index])) {
                Integer count = myMap.get(arr[index]);
                myMap.put(arr[index], ++count);
            } else {
                myMap.put(arr[index], 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(myMap);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. The above program prints
{E=5, D=1, C=2, B=3, A=5}
The expected result is
{A=5, E=5, B=3,  C=2, D=1}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char arr[] = {'A', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B','E','E'};
    int[] bridge = new int[256];
    int[] output = new int[256];
    for(char c : arr)
    {
        output[(int)c] = output[(int)c] + 1;
        bridge[(int)c] = bridge[(int)c] + 1;
    }
    Arrays.sort(output);
    boolean breakLoop = false;
    for(int index = 255; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        for(int inIndex = 0; inIndex <= bridge.length - 1; inIndex++)
        {
            if(output[index] != 0)
            {
                if(bridge[inIndex] == output[index])
                {
                    System.out.println((char)inIndex + " repeats " + output[index] + " times.");
                    bridge[inIndex] = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                breakLoop = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(breakLoop)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to to do this with HashMap alone, without using
>   ArrayList(or any other List implementations).

The answer is **NO** because the order of the entries of a `HashMap` is not guaranteed.

See in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) :

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

As you can see in the other answers you need something keeping the order of the elements (array, `List`...) or already sorted such as (an implementation of) `SortedMap`.